# Adding types to a recursive function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I've this below function to flatten an array item,

```
 private flatArray(data): [] {
    return data.reduce((accu, val) => (Array.isArray(val) ? accu.concat(this.flatArray(val)) : accu.concat(val)), []);
  }
```

Now I wanted to add types to the argument, Below is how I did it,

```
  private flatArray<T>(data: Array<Array<T>> | Array<T>): Array<T>
```

But I get this error,

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{
>   (callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number,
>   array: T[]) => T): T; (callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T,
>   currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T, initialValue: T): T;
>   (callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex:
>   number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;...' has no compatible
>   call signatures.ts(2349)

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: There is `.flat()` though ...

Comment: I can use that, but it dosen't support IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do

```
private flatArray<T>(data: Array<T | Array<T>>): Array<T>
```

A more robust approach in order to allow recursively nested arrays would be using a dedicated readonly type.

```
interface NestedArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<NestedArray<T> | T> { }

// ...

private flatArray<T>(data: NestedArray<T>): Array<T>
```

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCYEEpRwCeAPACoB8yEAHpCNhsvoaelhHgceVQD7JKyAN7IAvgCgJCADZwMTFsQBicsPWgThE5LuQAHKMABucSMhhqlpSgApsZuAC40mHNd4BKFx8o692npByFAQYACuUCDIDmBwAHSh2OFItv7BwbaICOEuZADaALoANMimMnnIAuzu3DYUnsgAvBTpGXq21vHAGNa25Y0A-MjZ4fEIAPYgCGa2YAAWPfGWZn0DjS6j41MzYP1wMp6epUVtQZ4A3G2SYkA)

Comment: Is there a way to do that without narrowing an array type to readonly?

Comment: You mean `NestedArray<T> extends Array<NestedArray<T> | T>`? Yes, that restricts the function to only accepting writable arrays.

Comment: Are you sure that this solves the problem described by the OP? Cause I don't see any difference between `Array<T> | Array<Array<T>>` and `Array<Array<T> | T>`

Comment: @JonasWilms one is array of T OR array of arrays of T; the other is Array whose elements can be either T or arrays of T simultaneously.

Comment: @zerkms sure, but the OP might *wants* the first. Not sure how this addresses the question. Also not sure how this is related to the `data.reduce(...)` type missmatch.

Comment: @JonasWilms I believe flattening accepts `Array<T | T[]>`, that's the point of the flattening. "flattening" of `T[]` to `T[]` makes no sense.

Comment: @zerkms flattening Array<Array<T>> to Array<T> would also makes sense. It depends if mixed depths should be accepted or not (the code shown by the OP supports that, so it would describe the behaviour more accurately). Nevertheless, this *does not adress the question*.

Comment: I believe it does - it types the OP's function which they couldn't type initially :shrug: